# How to merge 2 objects that contain an array of objects each?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an observable that gets data from an API, this is hooked up to a paginating feature. How do I add the response data object on to the variable which holds the first pages data. Essentially what [Array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does.

Right now each pagination will send a request to the API, even the previous pages since I am overwriting the data. I would like to add the array of objects (data.articles) on to the end of the category that is selected.

```
data = {
   general: undefined,
   business: undefined,
   entertainment: undefined,
   health: undefined,
   science: undefined,
   sports: undefined,
   technology: undefined
};

this.newsService.getNews(endpoint, params).subscribe(data => {
   this.data[category] = data.articles;
});
```

I expect the data to work like this:

If i show 1 article on the general tab, data.general will hold an array with one object in it. When i click next page, data.general should hold an array with 2 objects in it, and so on.

**Solution**

Array.prototype.push worked, for some reason when i initially tried this it didn't work. But i think that was because it was undefined initially. The below however works fine.

```
if (!this.data[category]) {
   this.data[category] = data.articles;
} else {
   Array.prototype.push.apply(this.data[category], data.articles);
}
```

Comment: Can you add actual results and expected results?

Comment: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) This seems very basic JS if I understood your question correctly. plenty of answers out there and documentation by googling. And this has nothing to do with angular ;)

Comment: You cannot concat or push 2 objects though can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, maybe this is what you want.

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.data[category], data.articles);
```

Above code will merge to array of objects into one and set to this.data[category]

Comment: This is not correct, the result of push is the new size of the resulting array which will be assigned to the `this.data[category]`

Comment: Hint: don't perform the assignment. Just do `Array.prototype.push......`

Comment: couldn't you just do `[this.data[category].push(data.articles)`

Comment: no, it can't work. because it's multi array. apply change array to argument for the final push method like this. `this.data[category].push(data.articles[0], data.articles[1], data.articles[2], ...);`

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but if you were interested in retaining the data in streams instead of in arrays, you can do something like this:

```
  // Action Stream
  private productInsertedSubject = new Subject<Product>();
  productInsertedAction$ = this.productInsertedSubject.asObservable();

  // Merge the streams
  productsWithAdd$ = merge(
    this.products$,                       // Original stream of data
    this.productInsertedAction$           // New data
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((acc: Product[], value: Product) => [...acc, value]),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
```

And if you were adding an array instead of a single value, the technique would be similar.